# Replace table with div, if table content matches a certain value

Tags: jquery, html-table

I cannot figure this one out.

I am wondering how I can conditionally change the table below to a div.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td>
     Text Here
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

There are multiple tables. Only the one that contains the specified text should be replaced with a `div`. And the contents of the `table` should but put inside the replacement `div`.

I am not sure if this can be done.

Comment: This is so basic, please read through [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/)...

Comment: Are you trying to replace the HTML `table` with a single `div`, and put the text contents of the `td` tag inside the `div`? ...with the end result in this case being `<div>Text Here</div>`?

Comment: @Dom Please give me a better direction.

Comment: @MattCoughlin I need the table to disappear for this specific text and be replaced by div.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replaceWith` method:

```
$('table').replaceWith(function() {
    return '<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MHuns/

If you want to select a table element that has a specific text content, you can use `filter` method:

```
$('table').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'Text Here';
}).replaceWith(function () {
    return '<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MHuns/2/

And a version of it implemented as a resuable jQuery plug-in:

http://jsfiddle.net/87XhU/

Comment: There are two other tables in the code which I need, so the table needs to be replaced by div based on the text inside the table.

Comment: @elena: ahhh... so that's what you meant. It wasn't entirely clear in the question.

Comment: @elenanincevic Do you mean that you have several table elements and you only want to replace one of them with a div element? Or do you mean that tables should be replaced according to their text contents?

Comment: @undefined the table should be replaced to div according to its text content.

Comment: @elenanincevic `replaceWith` callback function handles this. It replaces all the tables according to their text contents. http://jsfiddle.net/MHuns/1/

Comment: @undefined I see, so the code above should work, but where do I put the specific text, so it knows which table to replace?

Comment: @undefined this was close, but not exactly what I need. Please keep in mind that I have two other tables which I need to stay as tables.

Comment: @elenanincevic Okay, so you want to select an element that has a specific text content, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @undefined: the code above is not working for me. it is not working in the fiddle example either.

Comment: @undefined: my bad, it is working in fiddle, but for whatever reason it is not working for me.

Comment: @elenanincevic Have you put the code within document ready handler?

Comment: @undefined: yes, there are other script blocks which are working fine, so I am not sure what is the issue. Let me just check a few things.

Comment: @undefined and matt I just cannot get it to work for me. I have manipulated the other two tables with jQuery and this new table loads dynamically when the vacation settings are enabled from the admin panel. This new table is displaying a vacation note. this of course messes up my previous manipulation of the main table because this new table is now table 1 and it uses the styles of the main table. Of course I can ....

Comment: @undefined and matt .. Of course I can adjust the script by reassigning the table numbers, but when the vacation settings get disabled, everything will be messy again. I know this is supper confusing and I thank you for the help. At them moment, I just reassigned the table numbers and everything is back to normal. If you understand my problem and have a simple solution, please advise, if not, thank you for the help so far. Regards